# Data.c file generation

Tags: matlab, code-generation, simulink

i'm very new to matlab, i'm working on a software which needs the following files as input `model.c`,`model.h`,`model_data.c` for a particular simulink model. I have a model for which i can't generate `model_data` file using RTW, i have tried to get some information on the files generated by RTW, but i didnt get sufficient info. If there anybody who knows about the RTW please let me know the blocks which are required to generate `model_data.c`

thank you

Answer (score 0):

model_data.c is a conditionally created file (i.e. it is only created if it is needed, which depends on the way the model is set up for code generation).

For a discussion of the Simulink Coder build process, and what files get generated when, search the doc for the section titled "Files and Folders Created by Build Process".

Answer (score 0):

For others who need help in future.
Open the `Configuration Parameters` pane. Go to `Code Generation -> Optimization` and make sure that `Default parameter behavior` is set to `Tunable`.